# Moving wubi Ubuntu unstallation to partition separated from host partition

Tags: partitioning, wubi

I am trying to move my Ubuntu installation from disk image created using Wubi to the partition I would like to separate from the main Windows partition. Searching the Internet did not help yet. I am looking for some standard solution of this problem (which I suppose is pretty common).

In more details:

- I installed Ubuntu using wubi on Windows 7 partition,
- the size of the Ubuntu disk image is now 50GiB,
- I tried to apply standard "migrate to separate partition" script (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi), but cannot resize host (accessible through `/host`) partition due to it being used by several processes,
- I tried to use `gparted` from the Ubuntu install I want to move.

Some solutions I can think of are:

- resize the Windows partition and create new one, all from Windows 7 environment (eg. using Partition Magic or something similar),
- use some Live CD with gparted to resize the Windows partition and create new Ubuntu partition,

but I was thinking whether there is some more friendly solution (preferably automated one, some script etc.).

Please let me know, if there is some.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different media to run gparted from (a Live CD/USB seems like the obvious choice) or a different way to resize the partition (Windows 7 disk management?).

The only thing you need to do from the separate OS or method is the resize, the rest should be possible from the Ubuntu installation.

Partition Magic does not do things from the windows environment, it is replacing the windows kernel on boot to make the changes it needs to do, however, if you feel more comfortable with it, it can do what you need (resize the windows partition).

**Note:** keep in mind that partition resizes are not 100% reliable operation, and you should have a backup of your data prior to the operation.

Comment: Yeah, especially because the partition has NTFS file system. I suppose it is harder to resize it than FAT 16 or 32.

Comment: You can shrink the partition using Windows 7's disk management tool. Then gparted can create the partitions in the free space.

Comment: @bcbc I'm not a Windows 7 user, so didn't know this was an option, I'll edit my answer to reflect that.